# Bootstrap 4 "hidden" class doesn't work

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap v4 with it's default CSS and JS. I'm trying to apply the classes `hidden`, `hidden-XX-down` and `hidden-XX-up` to various divs, buttons, etc. But it doesn't seem to affect anything. All other classes work, except this one.

Here's an example:

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col col-10 offset-1 hidden-sm-down">

    <p class="text-primary text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

I want the paragraph to be invisible when I resize the window to a smaller width (sm-down), yet it remains visible and nothing happens.

Comment: why don't you define your own css, for example, use a `class="Andre-hidden"`  and in your CSS, write  `.Andre-hidden{display:none;}`

Comment: Could it be inheriting a property from a parent? Did you inspect the element?

Comment: @OscarZhang Bootstrap already has the `hidden` class, so I would consider it redundant to create another class to reach the same goal. Also, I'm still a noobie exploring Bs, so I'm trying to stick to bootstrap's default CSS for now...

Comment: @GaryHayes I did, but where should I be looking? (sorry for the noobiness)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `d-none`, `d-sm-none`, `d-md-none` etc.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

To only display for md up (hide for sm down) use:

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, using the `display` property definitely solved the problem.

In case anyone wonders why the `hidden` classes didn't work, it's very simple... They no longer exist in version 4 of Bootstrap. That's what you get from watching old tutorial videos.

Comment: There's the `[hidden]` attribute but it doesn't have size variations. e.g. `<div hidden></div>`

Answer (score 3):

If you already have code with the hidden class I recommend creating one:

```
.hidden{ 
    display: none;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap 4, the class invisible took the place of the class hidden.

Comment: Not quite. `invisible` toggles the CSS `visibility` property but does not affect the layout. So, an invisible element will still have the same shape as its visible counterpart. This is different from the behavior of the BS3 `hidden` class, which collapses the entire element.